# Can I use Jedis and Redisson together?

Tags: caching, redis, jedis, redisson

I have a `redis`database in my `spring boot`application. I use `Jedis` as my `Redis` client for retrieval, update and delete.

Now I'm willing to add distributed locks to my service, so I thought about using `Redisson` distributed locks. So my `Redisson` lock will be used to acquire and release lock around some logic of `Jedis` client.

Example:

```
redissonLock.acquire();

doSomeReadAndUpdateOperationsByJedis()

redissonLock.release();
```

Will using two `redis` clients work here? And if not, what is the best way to use a distributed lock with `Jedis`.

Comment: Yes, you can use them both.